# RuntimeError: Found dtype Long but expected Float when fine-tuning using Trainer API

Tags: python, pytorch, huggingface-transformers, bert-language-model, fine-tuning

I'm trying to fine-tune BERT model for sentiment analysis (classifying text as positive/negative) with Huggingface Trainer API. My dataset has two columns, `Text` and `Sentiment`, it looks like this.

```
Text                     Sentiment
This was good place          1
This was bad place           0
```

Here is my code:

```
from datasets import load_dataset
from datasets import load_dataset_builder
from datasets import Dataset
import datasets
import transformers
from transformers import TrainingArguments
from transformers import Trainer

dataset = load_dataset('csv', data_files='./train/test.csv', sep=';')
tokenizer = transformers.BertTokenizer.from_pretrained("TurkuNLP/bert-base-finnish-cased-v1")
model = transformers.BertForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained("TurkuNLP/bert-base-finnish-cased-v1", num_labels=1) 
def tokenize_function(examples):
    return tokenizer(examples["Text"], truncation=True, padding='max_length')

tokenized_datasets = dataset.map(tokenize_function, batched=True)
tokenized_datasets = tokenized_datasets.rename_column('Sentiment', 'label')
tokenized_datasets = tokenized_datasets.remove_columns('Text')
training_args = TrainingArguments("test_trainer")
trainer = Trainer(
    model=model, args=training_args, train_dataset=tokenized_datasets['train']
)
trainer.train()
```

Running this throws error:

```
Variable._execution_engine.run_backward(
RuntimeError: Found dtype Long but expected Float
```

The error may come from dataset itself, but can I fix it with my code somehow? I searched the Internet and this error seems to have been previously solved by "converting tensors to float" but how would I do it with Trainer API? Any advise is very highly appreciated.

Some reference:

https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/run-backward-expected-dtype-float-but-got-dtype-long/61650/10

Comment: Can you upload the code of `Trainer` and `datasets`?

Comment: is it possible your loss function is _binary_ cross-entropy instead of multi-variate cross-entropy?

Comment: try to increase `num_labels` to 2 instead of 1.

Comment: Here is my full dataset, I currently use a small sample of it: https://github.com/JereRajala00/training-data

Comment: @Shai Shouldn't binary cross-entropy be used with binary classification task? What do you think causes this error?

Comment: @Mr.Engineer in contrast to multi-label CE, the binary CE in pytorch expects the labels to be floats in range [0,1]

Comment: Alright... how would I use multi-label CE, or convert values of Sentiment-column into float?

Answer (score 3):

Most likely, the problem is with loss function. This can be fixed if you set up the model correctly, mainly by specifying the correct loss to use. Refer to this [code](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/05fa1a7ac17bb7aa07b9e0c1e138ecb31a28bbfe/src/transformers/models/bert/modeling_bert.py#L1563) to see the logic for deciding the proper loss.

Your problem has binary labels and thus should be framed as a single-label classification problem. As such, the code you have shared will be inferred as a regression problem, which explains the error that it expected float but found long type for target labels.

You need to pass the correct problem type.

```
model = transformers.BertForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained(
    "TurkuNLP/bert-base-finnish-cased-v1", 
    num_labels=1, 
    problem_type = "single_label_classification"
)
```

This will make use of BCE loss. For BCE loss, you need the target to float, so you also have to cast the labels to float. I think you can do that with the dataset API. See [this](https://discuss.huggingface.co/t/whats-the-best-way-to-change-convert-column-type-in-dataset/10711).

The other way would be to use a multi-class classifier or CE loss. For that, just fixing `num_labels` should be fine.

```
model = transformers.BertForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained(
    "TurkuNLP/bert-base-finnish-cased-v1", 
    num_labels=2,
)
```

Comment: Alright I was able to get past this error by converting Sentiment column into floats with ´pandas´ library. I'm training the model now, hopefully it I will be able to use it for inference.

Comment: Also, don't forget to use the correct problem type. Even though MSE may work, for classification you should use "*CE" loss

Answer (score 0):

Here I am assuming that you are trying to do one label classification, that is, to predict a single result instead of predicting multiple results.

But the loss function (I don't know what you are using but it is probably BCE) you use, expects a vector from you as a label.

So either you need to convert your labels to vectors as people suggested in the comments, or you can replace the loss function with Cross-entropy loss and change your number of label parameters with 2(or whatever). Both solutions will work.

If you want to train your model as multi-label classifier you can convert your labels to vectors with using sklearn.preprocessing:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

dataset = pd.read_csv("filename.csv", encoding="utf-8")
enc_labels = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
int_encoded = enc_labels.fit_transform(np.array(dataset["Sentiment"].to_list()))

onehot_encoder = OneHotEncoder(sparse = False)
int_encoded = int_encoded.reshape(len(int_encoded),1)
onehot_encoded = onehot_encoder.fit_transform(int_encoded)
for index, cat in dataset.iterrows():
    dataset.at[index , 'Sentiment'] = onehot_encoded[index]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could cast your data.

If you have it in [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html) format. You could do:

```
df['column_name'] = df['column_name'].astype(float)
```

If you have it in [HuggingFace](https://huggingface.co/docs/datasets/process) format. You should do something like that:

```
from datasets import load_dataset
dataset = load_dataset('glue', 'mrpc', split='train')
from datasets import Value, ClassLabel

new_features = dataset.features.copy()
new_features["idx"] = Value('int64')
new_features["label"] = ClassLabel(names=['negative', 'positive'])
new_features["idx"] = Value('int64')
dataset = dataset.cast(new_features)
```

Before:

```
dataset.features
```

```
{'idx': Value(dtype='int32', id=None),
 'label': ClassLabel(num_classes=2, names=['not_equivalent', 'equivalent'], id=None),
 'sentence1': Value(dtype='string', id=None),
 'sentence2': Value(dtype='string', id=None)}
```

After:

```
dataset.features
```

```
{'idx': Value(dtype='int64', id=None),
 'label': ClassLabel(num_classes=2, names=['negative', 'positive'], id=None),
 'sentence1': Value(dtype='string', id=None),
 'sentence2': Value(dtype='string', id=None)}
```

Answer (score 0):

The classification model does binary classification by default with the `num_labels` class set to `None`. setting your `num_labels` to `1` makes it a regression problem, hence the error you are experiencing. you can read more about it here:https://simpletransformers.ai/docs/classification-models/#classificationmodel